# How can I find out when I created a task on Any.do?

Tags: any.do

I have the contents of the task, but I've realised that the time at which it was created is as important as the contents!

It's my mistake for not writing down the time myself. I'm a bit stuck without it so if anybody knows how to get it back it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is clearly not possible. There is no way to find out the time when a task was added, there is no such feature in Any.DO.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but just because it's not obvious doesn't mean that it can't be done. Hence my asking..